# Lucene. How to build a term-doc matrix

Tags: lucene, matrix, tf-idf

I need to build that matrix but I can't find a way to compute normalized tf-idf for each cell. 
The normalization I would perform is cosine-normalization that is divide tf-idf (computed using  [DefaultSimilarity](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_3/api/core/index.html) ) per 1/sqrt(sumOfSquaredtf-idf in the column).

Does anyone know a way to perform that?
Thanks in advance
Antonio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way, not using Lucene, is described in [Sujit Pal's blog](http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2008/09/ir-math-with-java-tf-idf-and-lsi.html). Alternatively, you can build a Lucene index that has term vectors per field, iterate over terms to get idf, then iterate over term's documents to get tf.